# C++ No match for call to function

Tags: c++, string, lambda

I am making an option template class for an introduction to C++ class, part of the assignment is to implement a transform() function which takes a given function(f) and runs said function on the given option then returns a new option containing the new value, if it is empty an empty option is returned. 
Below is the header file:

```
#ifndef OPTION_HPP
#define OPTION_HPP

template<typename T>
class Option {
private:
T *value;   // nullptr if the Option is empty.

public:

// Applies f to the value in this Option. Returns a (copy of) this Option if f returns
// true; an empty option otherwise. If this Option is empty and empty Option is returned.
template<typename Function>
Option<T> filter( Function f ) const;

// Applies f to the value in this Option. Returns an Option containing the result of f.
// If this Option is empty an empty Option is returned.
template<typename U, typename Function>
Option<U> transform( Function f ) const;
};





template<typename T>
template<typename U, typename Function>
Option<U> Option<T>::transform( Function f ) const
{
if ( value != nullptr){
    return f(value);
}else{
    return value;
}
}

#endif
```

Below here is the class file:

```
#include <string>
#include "Option.hpp"

using namespace std;

Option<unsigned> process_string( const Option<string> &s )
{
// Filter out all strings with a length greater than or equal to 10.
Option<string> s1 = s.filter( [](const string &x) { return x.length()< 10; } );

// Transform the string into its length. Note that we must explicitly provide the type of U
// since the compiler can't deduce that type when it is only used in the return type.
return s1.transform<unsigned>( [](const string &x) { return x.length(); } );
}

int main(){



}
```

The problem is specifically with this portion:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename U, typename Function>
Option<U> Option<T>::transform( Function f ) const
{
if ( value != nullptr){
    return f(value);
}else{
    return value;
}
}
```

the error I am receiving is

> no match for call to ‘(process_string(const Option >&)::__lambda1) (std::basic_string* const&)’

Comment: `value`is a pointer. The parameter that `f` expects isn't a pointer.

Comment: Good job on narrowing it down to a specific portion.  You should remove the extra code, then tell what the values are that are being passed to and from the error portion.  In other words, only show the code that is necessary.

Comment: @cullub thanks for the tip, I edited it to narrow it down a little further.

Comment: Look at the error. It mentions an argument of type `std::basic_string* const&`. Your lamba has a parameter of type `const string&`. You forgot to dereference a pointer in `transform`: `f(*value)` or use the parameter type `const std::string*` in the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem I hope this may help. You want to apply f to the value currently in the option. In this case you need to return a new option containing a copy of the value in 'this' option.

```
template<typename T>
template<typename Function>
Option<T> Option<T>::filter( Function f )const{
    T t;

    if(f(t) == true){
        return Option( *this );
    }
    else{
        return Option();
   }

}
```